# Setting bounds in order to work on MMM modeling using SAS Procedures

Tags: sas, bounds

I am trying to build a MM model using a SAS procedure proc nlin on the following columns (attaching 4 lines of the actual data):

```
  ACVDO ACVFO   ACVFD   ACVPR
   7.84 12.82   1.21    44.34
   4.96 22.54   2.77    40.69
   6.51 12.23   0.63    32.42
   4.97 13.3    2.46    37.06
```

& the code I used is as follows:

```
  proc nlin data=Bags UNCORRECTEDDF; 
  parameters  b0=0 b1=0 b2=0 b3=0.004,b4=0 ; 
  bounds 0.004<b3<=0.00717 ;*/
  bounds b4>0.00253;
model mi_EQ = b0+b1*ACVDO+b2*ACVFO+b3*ACVFD+b4*ACVPR;

output out=nlinout predicted=pred ;
run;
```

There are other variables also that has to be included in the model but the problem that I am facing with this code is that in spite of setting a range the coefficients that I get are taking either of the extremes & not something within the range specified.

Can someone help me out as to how can I fix this issue?Is that I am missing out something while writing the code ?